# The given sign-in provider is disabled error while it is enabled in the console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript-firebase, svelte-native

I have created a new app with SvelteNative and I want to use firebase auth in it.
I installed @nativescript/firebase-core and @nativescript/firebase-auth in my project and I have added the file app/App_Resources/Android/google-service.json that I have downloaded on firebase console.

When I run this code :

```
const test = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await firebase()
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword("example@gmail.com", "123465798");
      console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  test();
```

I have the following error

> Error: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.

But in firebase console it is enabled:

[image: (screen of console)]

My project is brand new I have no other errors and no clues why this doesn't works.
I have checked the google-service.json file and all seems good (of course it's downloaded directly from my project in console).